# The specified directory is not a valid GlassFish installation

Tags: glassfish

I'm trying to install GlassFish 4 with Eclipse on Windows 7 64bit. Everything goes fine, but when I try to set server root here's what happens (dir exists):

[image: glassfish]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Glassfish installation folder contains a folder which is also named glassfish. This is the folder you have to put in the configuration field.

Change the path to:

```
c:/Glassfish/glassfish
```

Comment: Thank you, now it's working. I couldn't figure out what was wrong :)