# Not able to install Glasfish on mac. it says the specified directory is not a valid GlassFish installation

Tags: java, macos, glassfish

I tried creating a directory everywhere even in root folders. I also created a folder called Glasfish to save the server but still did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Just select the glassfish folder inside your glassfish folder :)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215552/the-specified-directory-is-not-a-valid-glassfish-installation) for some more details.

Comment: I did not clearly understand what is meant by glassfish folder inside glassfish folder. Do you mean I have to create two glassfish folder?

Comment: No, did you even install/extract the glassfish installation? Or do you think creating an empty folder somehwhere will automagically install a Glassfish server?

Comment: I did install the glassfish server from within the eclipse. It installed successfully but did not show where did it get installed. My current problem is when I try to add the server. After installation, I clicked the server link that prompted me to choose the Glassfish Sever . But I need to choose the directory for Glassfish location and i got a problem in this step

Comment: I know, and as I already wrote in the answer, you have to select the glassfish directory inside your glassfish directory, e.g. when you installed glassfish to `/bla/glassfish` then you have to choose `/bla/glassfish/glassfish`.